Does she use subjunctive mood in "can you imagine you would have ordered for 15?"?
From twomadexplorers:

at 00:20:04
can you imagine you would have ordered for 15?

Oxford uses a present tense

Close your eyes and imagine (that) you are in a forest.

or a future tense

I don’t imagine (that) they’ll refuse.

So, why does she use "would have" but not "will have"? Does it mean past future tense?

Would is not subjunctive. But that's just terminology. Where did you see this? Can you give more context. I'd guess she means imagining the order was made in the past, not imagining you're making the order, so "would" is used for a past event. Although it's a bit odd without context.

@Stuart F You can click the hyperlink-twomadexplorers. What she said is at 00:20:04 in the video.

Can you imagine [if you had not used your phone to translate how many you wanted] you would have ordered for 15.

The speaker isn't a native Anglophone. Don't copy her!

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a malformed one-off utterance from a non-native Anglophone

What she meant to convey was probably something like Can you imagine what it would have been like if you had ordered for 15?

There might be value in discussing the punctuation. What I heard when I listened was Can you imagine? You would have ordered for fifteen! Quite different from the OP's interpretation.

@PeterKirkpatrick: It's barely present, but I think she intends to say Can you imagine if you would have ordered for fifteen! Native Anglophones (especially Brits) almost never fully enunciate uncontracted subjunctive would in such contexts, but I often notice it from, for example, Germans speaking English. Brits invariably say if you had ordered... / if you'd ordered... there, not if you would have ordered....
